# How to mask Panda DataFrame based on the row and columns

Tags: pandas, nan, masking

I have the below DataFrame. I am looking for a way to automatically mask and choose values from specific row and columns without considering the nan values.

```
data=pd.DataFrame([[ np.nan,  0. ,  np.nan,  3. , 77. ],
   [ 5.6, 40. , 12. ,  9. ,  np.nan],
   [ 5.9,  np.nan,  5. ,  5. , 59. ],
   [ 4.8, 30. ,  np.nan, 11. , 30. ],
   [ 2.2,  6. , 15. ,  np.nan,  5. ]])
```

For example select rows 0 and 3 and columns 1,3, and 4 as below:

```
data_selected=pd.DataFrame([[ 0, 3, 77 ],[ 30,  11, 30 ]], index=[0,3],columns=[1,3,4])
```

Comment: What is the critirion for selecting the rows and cols? In the above example you could ,for instance, select rows 1 and 2 and columns 0, 2 and 3 and would also get 6 non-NaN-values?

Comment: if we select rows 1 and 2 and columns 0,2 and 3, we have one Nan value in column 4. I am looking for a way to select rows and columns of the dataframe with non-Nan- values in column 4. I found a solution. Please check it and give me your comments. thank you.

Comment: why do you think we get a NaN-value in column 4 if we only select columns 0,2 and 3? If you want " to select rows and columns of the dataframe with non-Nan- values in column 4", as you write, you can do it simply by `data.dropna(subset=[4])`. You solution below finds one subframe without NaNs, but there might be others, see my comment above. So it is not entirely clear, at least to me, what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: I am working on missing imputation using machine learning. This table is an example of the original table that is a matrix of M*N (time and space). The last column of the table is the target values. In order to train the machine learning algorithm on the table firstly, I should remove all row and columns containing NaN values, but in my case after using dropna command the output table is empty due to existence of NaN values in each row and columns. Therefore, I should select the best combinations of all row and columns containing non-NaN-values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. If you have better solution please give me your answer

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np

data=pd.DataFrame([[ np.nan,  0. ,  np.nan,  3. , 77. ],
   [ 5.6, 40. , 12. ,  9. ,  np.nan],
   [ 5.9,  np.nan,  5. ,  5. , 59. ],
   [ 4.8, 30. ,  np.nan, 11. , 30. ],
   [ 2.2,  6. , 15. ,  np.nan,  5. ]])


# interate over the data frame to find best combination of row and column for extraction
size_list=[]
index_list=[]
dfs=[]
for i in data.index:
    print(i)
    # interate over the dataframe and remove columns based on nan values in each row
    boolean_ind=data.loc[i, :].isnull()  
    ex7=data[data.columns[boolean_ind==False]]
    # after removing the columns with nan value in row, use dropna command to romove other nan values from the selected dataframe (ex7)
    ex7_drop=ex7.dropna()
    # append each dataframe into the list to choose it after finding the best dataframe based on the size
    dfs.append(ex7_drop)
    # compute shape of the selected dataframe to choose the beset dataframe based on the size
    size=ex7_drop.shape[0]*ex7_drop.shape[1]
    size_list.append(size)
    # put row index of each dataframe into the index_list to easily select the selected rows from the base dataframe
    index_list.append(ex7_drop.index)

# select best index based on the max size
max_size_index=index_list[size_list.index(max(size_list))]
selected_df=dfs[size_list.index(max(size_list))]
```